# CyanogenMod USB tether

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-milestone, usb-tethering

I can't seem to find the option to enable USB tether in CyanogenMod 7.0.1 . Several pages and forum threads mention a checkbox under Wireless & network setting, but i don't have it. 
Is there anything i need to do to get this to show up? Is this not supported anymore? What USB mode should I select? The phone is a Motorola Milestone, computer runs Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Milestone is an unofficial port, and USB tethering is not yet supported. There is a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod4milestone/issues/detail?id=439&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Version%20Owner%20Summary) on their issue tracker for this.

---

The [most recent comment](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod4milestone/issues/detail?id=439#c6) on the above mentioned ticket indicates that it's been fixed as of 7.1.0-RC15 and should now be included.